# How to ignore meta tags when using the AntiXssOutputEncoder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using an Anti XSS Output encoder similar to the one htat Phil Hacck put forward [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx)

Unfortuantely, it's running rampant over my Site.master and fouling up the meta-tags like so:

```
<meta name="robots" content="all,&#32;follow" />
```

And in Site.master it is written simply as:

```
<meta name="robots" content="all, follow" />
```

Which would be the correct output under normal circumstances, but I'd prefer to be able to skip the meta tags in the site.master.

Is there a way to do this while running your own HttpEncoder?

Comment: How are you generating this tag in your markup?

Comment: It's not generated - its written in the site.master

Comment: So how is the AntiXSS encoder getting involved? If you have `<%: %>` in your site.master... could you simply replace it with `<%= %>`?

Comment: You probably need to read the original article Phil Haack wrote. HttpEncoders process all output before it is sent. 

The tag is just written as plain HTML, no <%= or <%:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you get that information, but you could try whitelisting allowed values, if you don't have many meta tags like this.

A simplified version would be:

```
protected override void HtmlAttributeEncode(string value, TextWriter output)
{
    if (value != "all,&#32;follow")
    {
        output.Write(AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(value));
    } 
    else
    {
        output.Write(value);
    }
}
```

Not ideal, but insofar as I can see, [HttpEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.httpencoder_members.aspx) doesn't hand you context.